# PDFsharp Change Origin

Tags: rotation, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I'm using [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.net/Overview.ashx) to draw lines of a fairly complex shape. To simplify this process and make it more comprehendable, I would like to change the origin from the top left corner of the page to the bottom left. Currently, changing the origin is [not yet implemented](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PDFsharp/PdfSharp/XGraphics/P/PageOrigin). Is there a way I can relocate the origin to the bottom left using methods like `RotateTransform` and `TranslateTransform` or otherwise? As best as I can tell, the rotate transform rotates about the origin. There may be a trick I don't know. Using

```
gfx.RotateTransform(180);
gfx.TranslateTransform(-612, -792); // Assumes 8.5 inch x 11 inch at 72 points/inch
```

I can shift it to the bottom right so that x increases going left, but added text is upside down.[image: Generated PDF]

Is there a way to truly move the origin to the bottom left so that y increases going up and x increases going right? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
ThomasH's answer moves the origin to the bottom left, but the text is still flipped. Is there a way to overcome this? See the self contained example here: http://pastebin.com/fgfjDXF1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `TranslateTransform` and `ScaleTransform(1,-1)` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That moved the origin to the bottom left, but the text is still upside down. Is this a side effect of the ScaleTransform? If so is there some modification that could avoid it?

Comment: Here's a self contained example illustrating the text problem: http://pastebin.com/fgfjDXF1

Comment: Solved the upside down text for my specific application by using the Save() and Restore() methods of XGraphics. I do two passes. Save the initial state. First scaling and translation per this answer, draw the shape, and record the points where the labels should be drawn. Then restore the initial state. Now the second pass involves doing the translation but not the scaling, and then writing the labels at the points. This way they appear right side up and in the proper position.